# Implementation of JSON in Embedded webserver

Tags: php, api, jsonp, json

I am very new in JSON , I hope to get clear viw regarding my question.

In my current project , we are going to implement JSON in Embedded web server. So I got more doubts regarding the scripting JSON in Embedded server and extracting that information by the client APP ( Smart phones , tablets etc.). Just to get data from server to client upon request. Please provide me some brief idea on it in both the  server side for storing data and client for extracting that data and the bit procedure of it.

THe variable need to hold the dynamic data. Suppose the microcontroller sense temperature (its a dynamic data that changes every time), and this current temperature need to saved in the variable and upon request from client that current temperature stored in that variable need to be passed to the client. How it can be perfromed?

Comment: Have you looked into [JSON-P](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Mar/JSON-P-what-what-s-not-and-how-works-205)?

Comment: We don't provide sample scripts.